# Using the website www.codepad.org can you link the math library?

Tags: c

I need an online sandbox for C so I can compile and run C on any computer easily, but my program requires me to link against the math library.

Can I use `-lm` on codepad or another online sandbox for C programming?

Comment: Did you try to do so?  I just attempted to load OpenMP with it (something that's found on Linux systems) and it wasn't available.  So, not sure it is or isn't.

Comment: I computed Pi on codepad and it must have included math.h or compiler builtins because the math functions worked.

Comment: @hellork: GCC can optimise out some calls to math functions (meaning you don't always need to link the math library), and it looks like codepad doesn't link it - see http://codepad.org/avs0NIre and http://codepad.org/about

Comment: The code in your other question compiles and runs on http://ideone.com/

Comment: @hellork: Computing π doesn't necessarily require the math library; simple floating-point arithmetic (`+` `-` `*` `/`) is built in.

Comment: Yes, I know all that, thanks @TimothyJones, Keith, but the comments might help someone visiting, so keep 'em coming... My codepad code did indeed use the compiler built in sqrt function: http://codepad.org/9arPadCj Not even close to the ideal way to computer Pi, but I had read that it could be done with circle area, so there you go, public domain. See if you can spot the cheat I installed to make it more accurate than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently - since you can't change the compiler options. From the [about page](http://codepad.org/about), these are the compiler options currently in use for C:

> -O -fmessage-length=0 -fno-merge-constants -fstrict-aliasing -fstack-protector-all

However, you could always ask them to include `-lm`:

> codepad was written (and still is being written!) by Steven Hazel. Please contact me at sah@codepad.org if you have any problems or feature requests.

Also, as a commenter points out, It looks like the compiler at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) links with the math library.